# Pkg giving issues with typescript node app

Tags: node.js, typescript, package, exe, pkg-config

I'm trying to pack my node app into an exe by using "pkg". I use typescript and when I run pkg index.ts --debug I'm getting this error.

> Node.js v18.5.0
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node18-x64 for file /snapshot/api/index.ts C:\snapshot\api\index.ts:1 (function (exports,
> require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as http from
> "http";

Looks like a Typescript incompatibility issue. How can I make "pkg" work with Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote the same API with JS instead of TS I was able to successfully compile with "pkg".

Comment: Hi, it's better to edit your first question, including  this one. This is not an answer!